# multi user login validation unsuccessful using servlet and jsp in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have created a Login page with three fields Usertype, Username and Password. Usertype has select box (or select tag), Username has textfield and Password also has textfield. To login every field has to be correct. The problem is I am successfully able to validate username and password but unable to do with usertype, username and password. I have login.java and index.jsp.

**Login.java**

```
package roseindia.net;

import java.io.*;

//import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import java.sql.*;

/*** Servlet implementation class Login
***/
 @WebServlet(description = "Login Servlet", urlPatterns = { "/login" })
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Login() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
         * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("We are service method of servlet");

        /*
        String username="user";
        String password="root";
        */


        String un=request.getParameter("username");
        String pw=request.getParameter("password");
        String ut=request.getParameter("usertype");

        String msg=" ";

        Connection conn=null;
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName="userlogindb";
        String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String dbUserName="root";
        String dbPassword="root";

        try{
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,dbUserName,dbPassword);
        String strQuery="select * from registerutable where username='" + un + "' and    password1='" + pw + "' and usertype='" + ut + "'";
        Statement st= conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(strQuery);
        if(rs.next())
        {
            msg="Hello "    + un + "! Your login is successful";
            request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
            RequestDispatcher  req=request.getRequestDispatcher("/successful.jsp"); 
            req.forward(request, response);
        } else
        {
            msg="Hello "    + un + "! Your login failed";
            request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
            RequestDispatcher req=request.getRequestDispatcher("/failed.jsp"); 
            req.forward(request, response);
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
        if(un.equals(username) && pw.equals(password))
        {
           msg="Hello " + un + "! Your login is successful"; 
        }
        else
        {
           msg="Hello " + un + "! Your login failed"; 
        }
        */
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("<font size='6' color=red>" + msg + "</font>");


    }

   }
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform" action="login" method="post">
<div style="width:300px;margin:0 auto;">
<p>User Type: <select>
                <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                <option value="proj-coordinator">Project Co-ordinator</option>
                <option value="proj-manager">Project Manager</option>
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
          </select>
</p>
<p>User Name: <input type="text" name="username"></p><br>
<p>Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" name="password"></p><br>
<center><input type="submit" value="Login"></center>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I m running this program and validating it with correct values then also it is showing Login unsuccessful/failed page.
Please resolve this issue

Comment: what about name property for select type in jsp..?? you missed it or it is a typo..??

Comment: SivaS I have added name property of <select> tag to usertype but still it is not validating and showing login failed page. Then what would be the problem.

Comment: If you submitting page by post method, then in servlet class there  need doPost() method to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Select Type in jsp as follows

```
  User Type: <select name="usertype">
                <option value="employee">Employee</option>
                <option value="proj-coordinator">Project Co-ordinator</option>
                <option value="proj-manager">Project Manager</option>
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: SivaS I have added name property of <select> tag to usertype but still it is not validating and showing login failed page

Answer (score 0):

@Atiq : the code which you have putted above, it seems that you have not set the `name` property of `<select>` tag to `usertype` in the jsp.
Try to add this and then check, it should work.

Comment: Suneet Bansal I have added name property of <select> tag to usertype but still it is not validating and showing login failed page

Comment: you need to do in the following way : <select name="usertype">...</select>

Comment: try to do sysout for un, pw, ut and strQuery and then check whether these values exists in the DB or not and the query is building correctly or not. If possible then attached the result in your comment.

Comment: I have sysout it shows me the following in console : The sql is select * from registerutable where username='emp3' and password1='emp3' and usertype='null'

Comment: usertype is coming as null this is the reason your are getting authentication failed page. Try to check why it is coming as null.